# Keys for decrypting msgtore.db.crypt14 whatsapp file

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to copy my own whatsapp conversations and create a local sqlite database where I can execute queries over it. As far as I understand, the encrypted sqlite db files in whatsapp can be decrypted with the keys that the app has stored locally in my phone. So far I have not been able to find these keys.

Where is whatsapp storing the encryption keys in the Android phones and how can I retrieve them?

Or is there a better way to copy all my conversations from whatsapp and have these available in my computer locally? (I am trying achieve a programatic solution so I would like to avoid having to manually export each conversation using the app.)

Comment: The key is stored in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key`. You need root access to be able to read this file.